# UTF-8 Characters not displaying with Launch4j

Tags: java, utf-8, launch4j

I wrote a version of poker that uses special characters to represent the particular suits of the cards (for example, ♠) when printed to the console. Everything is fine in Eclipse, it prompts me to save as UTF-8 and it works just fine. However, when I converted my runnable jar to an exe via Launch4j, it will show a hand as [K ?, A ?] for instance.
I attempted to add the JVM option `-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"` but have not found any luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using properties resource file?

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: What happens when you ran the compiled jar (separate from eclipse) before you package it with Launch4j? I suspect it is not a Launch4j issue, but a resource/font issue.

Comment: Same deal, the program will show ? instead of the characters when I run the jar file from command prompt.

Comment: As suspected it is an issue with the support font type of the console. Some more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360830/printing-unicode-to-console

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I found an answer. In java you need to create a seperate PrintStream which is needed whenever you want to print any Unicode Character, [like so.](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050208053951714) Then you need to type `cmd /c chcp 65001` to change the recognized CharSet, then you will be able to run the program just fine.